# root cause behing following kafka exception

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

We have recently encountered following exception on one of the environment:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner.partition(DefaultPartitioner.java:70)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.partition(KafkaProducer.java:721)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:459)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:430)
```

What could be possible root cause behind such exception?

Looking at the source code following method is returning null values for partitions: `org.apache.kafka.common.Cluster#partitionsForTopic`

Comment: What version of the driver is this?

Comment: kafka-clients API version: 0.10.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have been hit by this defect:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3562

Even if the root cause is different, some race condition between partition assignment and metadata fetch, still that fix may help, so I suggest updating. 0.10.0.0 is quite old by now and later versions are a lot more stable.